# How to declare methods in objective c outside the interface?

Tags: xcode, methods, declaration

When a method is declared in .h file is detected by intelisense and the warnings are not raised, when the method is used in .m file.

When a method is declared only in .m file, the intelisense doesn't detect it if is declared below the method where is being used.

To avoid the warnings there is a flag in xcode, but I prefer don't disable it.

There is any way to declare the methods in .m in order to be detected by intelisense and without the warning?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways to fix it:

Either: Use a [class extension](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW2) to declare private methods at the top of the .m file:

```
@interface Foo ()

- (void)privateMethod;

@end
```

Or: Upgrade to Xcode 4.3.1, which contains a more recent version of clang. This newer version of the compiler does not need previously declared methods to call them in the same compilation unit.

Class extensions are still good for compatibility or to declare private properties, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a category to declare additional methods on a class.

For instance, adding this at the top of your .m file:

```
@interface MyClass (PrivateCategory)

-(void)foo;
-(void)bar;

@end
```

will let Xcode know that `MyClass` additionally responds to `foo` and `bar`. The `(PrivateCategory)` tells the compiler that you're adding methods that should be "grouped" under the category `PrivateCategory`. You can pick whatever name you want, or even no name at all (although an "anonymous category" has slightly different semantics).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But directly in the implementation file, is it possible?

Comment: Since the introduction of class extensions there's a dedicated mechanism for private declarations which should be preferred.

Comment: @NemeSys, yes. Any declaration can go in a `.m` file. You usually put global declarations in .h file because you can include these declarations in other files; but whatever is valid in a .h file is also valid in a .m file.